# htaccess два домена, на одном возращать 404 на другом показывать сайт

Tags: .htaccess, домен

Есть два домена, site.ru и site2.ru, оба домена ссылаются на один сайт.
Нужно чтобы при заходе на site.ru выдавало 404 ошибку, а при заходе на site2.ru нормально показывался сайт.

Как такое сделать в htaccess?

Comment: Вы УВЕРЕНЫ что вам нужно именно через .htaccess? Есть более цивильный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше уж делать чтобы при заходе на один автоматически переносило на второй домен чем лепить ошибку 404.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^site2$
RewriteRule ^ http://site2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

а в вашем случае просто сделать отвязку домена и он сам вникуда будет смотреть

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine off в .htaccess
и уберите индексный файл, либо переименуйте его